I can't import docx files in Outline Word From Powerpoint
Hello everyone I can't import docx files from slides from outline in Powerpoint. I use Windows and Office 365. Therre are only available .RTF files but not docx. Anyone could help me?
[enter image description here](enter image description here)
Help and if anyone could explain to me why I can't import docx files into my powerpoint
